# ImportError - Module Not Found?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My directory structure is:

```
project_folder/
..my_project/
....server/
......server.py
......api.py
```

When I'm in the `project_folder` and run `python3 my_project/server/server.py`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project'` with the line of code:

```
from my_project.server.api import app as application
```

Weirdly, when I run my tests with Pytest everything passes. I've been trying to solve my problem without using this code snippet, which I always see recommended to solve these problems:

```
import sys
from os import path
sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.abspath(__file__) ) ) )
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module you try to call is already in the same package, so just do

```
from api import app as application
```

Comment: Thanks @Zcode. If I'm trying to call another module from `server.py` (stored in `my_project/other_module/module.py`, how could I do that?

Comment: Then you can do  "from import ..other_module.module". You should see the Python documentation about packages.

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty `__init__.py` file in my_project and server folders.

Answer (score 0):

run this `cd my_project/server/` and then `python server.py`

 Or remove this line from server.py `import my_project`

And if you are trying to make a module add

## `__init__.py`

to your server dir